# How to include only a single part of the dependency in android Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to add **Material Design components in a project** that is exported from the Unity for android. *(Unity adds the aar file for the dependency in library folder of the :unityLibrary module)*

The problem is material design dependency

```
implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0')
```

trying to add androidx.{..} dependency that are already in the project with other version

```
// dependency already present
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation(name: 'androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater.asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.coordinatorlayout.coordinatorlayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.core.core-1.3.2', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.cursoradapter.cursoradapter-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.customview.customview-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.documentfile.documentfile-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.drawerlayout.drawerlayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.exifinterface.exifinterface-1.3.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.fragment.fragment-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.interpolator.interpolator-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.legacy.legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager.localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.print.print-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.slidingpanelayout.slidingpanelayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout.swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.versionedparcelable.versionedparcelable-1.1.0', ext:'aar')
implementation(name: 'androidx.viewpager.viewpager-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
implementation project('FirebaseApp.androidlib')
implementation project('FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib')
// Material Design adds androidx.{..} dependency with other version 
implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0')
```

and gives the error

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:) .......... and so on ..........

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

so, I tried to exclude the androidx dependency using exclude keyword

```
// Material Design
implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'androidx'
}
```

but nothing really happen .

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not correctly exclude the module.

from the gradle examples:

```
implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
```

in your case to exclude `androidx.core:core:1.5.0` I believe you need:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
}
```

Comment: It works, but there are a lot of dependencies being asked for by material design, is there any way to exclude them all with a sing exclude statement.

Comment: I am still having an issue, Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap found in modules jetified-androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and jetified-androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0), I already excluded androidx.arch

Comment: you have to make sure you have the exact names of the group and module. Probably it is not called "androidx.arch".
Also, there is a reason why those dependencies are there, they are required. What you are running in though is a conflict of specific dependencies that cannot be resolved (normally gradle automatically resolves such conflicts). Disabling all dependencies would stop your code from compiling.

Comment: I am excluding it, like this
        exclude group: 'androidx.arch', module: 'arch'
but still show the error

Comment: That group does not exist on maven central, but there is a 'androidx.arch.core' group with module 'core-common' https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.arch.core/core-common
the group/module name can sometimes be derived from the jar name but often its different. You have to somehow (for instance with gradle dependency tree or other tools) find the actual group/artifact (or module) names